# Do words like Jinn have plural?

Tags: word-usage

Jinn or djinn is a word we middle east people use for demons. I found this word in an English dictionary too, but it seems that this word is never used in plural form. For example, when you want to say "I was attacked by three demons" it works, and Microsoft Word did not underline it, but when using "Jinns" it seems not correct.
What do you think about it? What is the right way to say "three jinns"?

Comment: English speakers may use either "jinn" or "jinns" as a plural. See the usage note in the [American Heritage Dictionary entry](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=jinn).

Comment: There has been the usual mixup between _jinn_ and _jinni_, plus the much more common English spelling as _genie_ (pl. _genies_) to contend with, so using anything approximating Arabic spelling is tricky, and depends on the intentions of the writer as perceived by the reader. There is of course no problem in speech, only spelling.

Comment: The French want a say about this, too. There are works titled *Les Djinns* by Cesar Franck, Gabriel Fauré, Louis Vierne, and Victor Hugo.

Comment: I know this isn't French StackExchange, but the French seem to primarily spell it *djinn* and use *djinn* as singular and *djinns* as plural ([TLFi](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/djinn)). The spelling is based on French pronunciation principles, but I guess the singular/plural is just habit.

Answer (score 2):

In various places I've read the word Jinn as plural itself and Jinni as the singular.

see http://www.dictionary.com/browse/jinn

Comment: The plural of **fish** is (annoyingly) both **fish** *and* **fishes**. However, there are some subtle distinctions between their uses. Like **fish**, several words (**sheep** also comes to mind—and at least it has no **sheeps** alternative . . .) have a plural that is still spelled the same way as the singular.

Answer (score 0):

In basic terms, it does not much matter if you use Djinn as the singular or plural. The singular/plural distinction has been lost in translation.

OED:

> **jinn, n.**
>
> **Etymology:** < Arabic jinn, collective plural, demons, spirits, angels; **singular jinnī** (see jinni n.).
>
> In Muslim demonology, an order of spirits lower than the angels, said to have the power of appearing in human and animal forms, and to exercise supernatural influence over men. **More commonly used as a singular to denote one of this class.**

> a. (as singular).
>
> 1838   Torrens Arab. Nts. I. 16   *Tale of the Merchant and the Jin*
>
> [1841 Lane I. 44 *Story of the Merchant and the Jinnee*].

> b. (as plural).
>
> 1838   E. W. Lane in tr. Thousand & One Nights (1839) I. i. Notes 30   *The species of Jinn is said to have been created some thousands of years before Adam.*
>
> 1884   J. Payne tr. Tales from Arabic I. 272   *Arise, let us depart this place, for it is full of Jinn and Marids.*

Answer (score -2):

The correct way to say it would be 3 Djinn. Djinn is plural, and the correct singular form would be djinni or jinni. Saying djinns is ridiculous. Although it has been incorrectly anglicised into djinns and used by many, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have an authoritative source for your claim? And did you perchance read the other answer? It basically says the same thing. Please take the [Tour] to familiarize yourself with our platform.